# Monotone Convergence Theorem in Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

(b) If $(a_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers such that the set of partial sums $\{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k|n \in J\}$ is bounded, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges.

If I am not wrong for this statement to be true it needs to be specified that the "terms are non-negative" so that the sequence of partial sums is montone increasing. By monotone convergence theorem the sequence of partial sums is convergent, therefore the series too is convergent.

Comment: $1-1+1-1+...$ contradicts (b)

Comment: You are correct that this is the monotone convergence theorem with the assumption of non-negativity dropped, and likely the point of the exercise to see that this condition is vital to the result. But there are other conditions that could be substituted, such as "alternating and $|a_n| \to 0$" (though that one makes the boundedness of the partial sums redundant).